Hangfire authorization not working for ms entra group (401)
I have a small api project .net 4.8 and have hangfire dashboard access authorized to a group
In api web.config there is group name defined as below:
<add key="HangfireDashboardManagerRoles" value="GROUP\MYGROUP1" />

Hangfire Authorization Filter:
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using Hangfire.Annotations;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Microsoft.Owin;

   
    public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            var owinContext = new OwinContext(context.GetOwinEnvironment());
            var user = owinContext.Authentication.User;
            return user.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HangfireDashboardManagerRoles"]
                        .Split(new[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => x.Trim())
                        .Any(user.IsInRole);
        }
    }


Start up

//including reference for filter

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace xxx
{
    //owin startup
    public class Startup
    {
        private const string HangfireBaseUrl = "/bcgjobs";

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Guard.NotNull(app, nameof(app));
            app.SetupJobDashboard(HangfireBaseUrl, "HangfireDbContext", "MyApp", new DashboardOptions
            {
                AppPath = HangfireBaseUrl,
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
            });
        }
    }
}

I have to set it up to an ms entra group msentragrp1 and so made the following change
<add key="HangfireDashboardManagerRoles" value="azuredomain\msentragrp1" />

But I get on browsing myip:port/api/bcgjobs: Http Error 401, This page isn't working right now. How do I complete my set up so that members of my ms entra group can browse the hangfire dashboard?
Edit 1:
I referred some documentation and locally I get the hangfire dashboard but I am still struggling with authorizing ms entra group
Here are the changes:
Start up
private const string HangfireBaseUrl = "/bcgjobs";

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Guard.NotNull(app, nameof(app));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDbContext");
            app.SetupJobDashboard(HangfireBaseUrl, new DashboardOptions
            {                
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
            });
        }

Filter:
public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            var owinContext = new OwinContext(context.GetOwinEnvironment());
            var user = owinContext.Authentication.User;
            return user.Identity.IsAuthenticated; 
        }


Any suggestion how can this be achieved with a custom filter suitable for .net4.8? Also ensuring it has to support azure ad group.
